# How to manage results in RxJava with Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a Retrofit request API call with RxJava. All works well.

How I can optimise this code. I'm a new one with RxJava.
I would be grateful for a small example code or link. 
Thanks.

```
Observable<Review> observer = Observable.just(review);
    observer.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .map(new Func1<Review, Uri>() {

                @Override
                public Uri call(Review review) {
                    Uri uri = null;
                    /// Some code
                    return uri;
                }
            }).subscribe(new Action1<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Uri uri) {
            if(uri != null) {
                Api.Reviews reviewApi = retrofit.create(Api.Reviews.class);
                Observable<BaseResponse<Review>> reviews = reviewApi.createReview(authToken, review);
                reviews.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .map(new Func1<BaseResponse<Review>, Void>(){
                            @Override
                            public Void call(BaseResponse<Review> response) {
                               //Code Here
                                return null;
                            }
                        }).subscribe();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options: map, doOnNext, flatMap, etc., depending on what do you want to do with the retrofit result afterwards. For example:

```
reviews
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(r -> {
    try {
        someDB.save(r);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return r;
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> { }, e -> { log(e); });
```

or

```
reviews
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.doOnNext(r -> {
    try {
        someDB.save(r);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> { }, e -> { log(e); });
```

or

```
reviews
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMap(r -> {
    try {
        someDB.save(r);
        return Observable.empty(); // or Observable.just(r);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return Observable.error(ex);
    }
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(v -> { }, e -> { log(e); });
```

Comment: side note: to get the nice lambda notation, [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

Comment: the first map example is a bit awkward. the third with flatmap would make more sense if `save(r)` returned an observable, this way it would be nicely chained.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've published some examples of RxJava usage (https://github.com/dawidgdanski/rx-java-handies). If you find it useful while investigating the API for your cases I'll be glad to help you out.